# Dagger doesn't like constructors that throw exceptions

Tags: java, android, dagger, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger in my android application to simplify dependency injection. It looks like Dagger 2.0 doesn't support constructors that throw exceptions. Is there a solution to this?

It doesn't seem feasible to refactor and create an init method that throws exceptions instead, because having to call init on the entire chain of dependent objects reintroduces the problems that dagger solves.

Comment: Other than wrapping your exceptions to be runtime OR handling the exceptions in your module's provider method at top level, I don't think so.

Comment: Side note: you may want to describe behavior you are looking for... In general there is not too many options when constructor throws as there is no resulting object that can be used - so propagating exception to caller is almost only reasonable approach.

Comment: For example, I have a class that wraps a Uri, the constructor does some validitation, checking that certain query parameters are present for example. If not, I think it makes most sense to throw an exception.

Comment: I think you should provide a factory for that Uri wrapper thing in your module, and then call a method on that factory which will do the validation and then construct an instance of the Uri wrapper thing only if it's actually valid. This is really not something that Dagger2 should know, considering you cannot customize the internal provider methods that Dagger2 generates "in case of an error during binding all your stuff together".

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear to generated code what should happen when an exception is thrown during a constructor. Should classes that depend on instances of this class be required to catch the exception somehow? Should the application crash if the exception is thrown? In general, Dependency Injection tries to separate the dependent class from knowing the construction strategy of its dependencies and this would violate that principle.

One option is to use a `@Module` which `@Provides` the instance(s). Then, if the exception is thrown, that `@Provides` method can return a sensible default. You could also consider using `Optional<>` to indicate that the object could not be constructed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you can create the instances separately, implementing your own exception handling, then you can pass them to the module.

Example:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    private final Configuration config;

    public MyModule(Configuration config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Configuration configuration() {
        return this.config;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SomethingElse somethingElse(Configuration config) {
        return new SomethingElse(config);
    }
}
```

and you pass the instance from outside

```
try {
    config = new Configuration(...);
} catch (...) {}

ServiceComponent serviceComponent = DaggerMonkMain_ServiceComponent.builder()
            .myModule(new myModule(config))
            .build();
```

This is only practical if the number of classes that can throw exceptions during creation is small.